# GLSL: Determine if vector is not zero

Tags: glsl

I use a vertex and fragment shader pair for drawing cylinder impostors for molecular visualization. The shader renders of the order 500.000 cylinders (bonds) on the screen. Clearly, shader optimization is an issue.

For each rendered cylinder, I have to determine whether some vec3, say u, is NOT the zero vector. I might do:

```
dot(u,u) != 0.0

(u.x != 0.0) || (u.y != 0.0) || (u.z != 0.0)

any(notEqual(u, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)))
```

What is the fastest way of doing this? Alternative solutions to the above are more than welcome.

Best regards,

Mads

Comment: Do you only care about the case where the vector is not ***exactly*** *0.0* for all components? Since this is floating-point, there are plenty of situations where if you did the math with pen and paper it would come out exactly **0.0**, but when done in the shader might be **+/- 0.0000...1.** Really the only time you would want to test a floating-point number against a specific value is when you explicitly set it to that value somewhere, or know that the math will not suffer from precision errors.

Comment: When I display the cylinder, I need to rotate it into place, i.e. align it along its axis v. To do that, I calculate u = cross(v,z), where v is the cylinder axis and z is the z-axis. If u != 0, it should be normalized, i.e. u=normalize(u). The situation, u=0, may easily happen if a cylinder (bond) is aligned along the z-axis. So I need to check for u != 0, and would like to do this as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Because precision really is an issue with floating point calculations, it should be taken into account, really.

```
#define PRECISION 0.000001

float val = ...;
// returns 1.0 if it's in the range, 0.0 otherwise
float is_not_too_close_to_zero = step(-PRECISION, val) * (1.0 - step(PRECISION, val));
```

This technique could then be combined to produce more complex checks.